# Random Line Appeared In VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Not sure how or why but this black line/seperator appeared in my VSCode Editor, it seems the seperate thee code and the parent function. I want to get rid of it but I'm not sure how can I do that. I'm looking forward for solutions.
[image: The problem]

I looked through settings, and searched possible fixes but I couldn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is the "sticky scroll" feature. It is intended to easier show the structure of the document you are working with.

[image: A VS Code editor showing how the sticky scroll feature works]

You can disable it by setting `editor.stickyScroll.enabled` to false in settings.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_71#_sticky-scroll